# Changing items in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to change all items in array A (in axis=1) into 0, according to the following criteria (toy code):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,3], [2,5], [6,2]] )
B = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,2,2],[0,0,0,2,0],[6,6,0,0,0]])

for i in A:
    if i[1]<=2:
        B[B==i[0]]=0

# result

>>> B
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But, in numpy way, that is NO 'for' loops :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional list comprehension to create a list of the first value in a tuple pair where the second value is less than or equal to two (in the example for `A`, it is the last item which gives a value of `6`).

Then use slicing with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to find the elements in `B` what are contained within the values from the previous condition, and then set those values to zero.

```
target_val = 2
B[np.isin(B, [a[0] for a in A if a[1] <= target_val])] = 0

>>> B
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Alternatively, you could also use `np.where` instead of slicing.

```
np.where(np.isin(B, [a[0] for a in A if a[1] <= target_val]), 0, B)
```

Comment: A comprehension might not count as a for loop, but it's not getting full use out of Numpy either :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel On a sample size where `B` is 100k as large as above, I see my approach as slightly faster (5.27 ms vs 5.77). I also added `(1, 1)` to `A` to given an extra data point.  `np.where` approach took almost 2x the time.

Comment: Interesting. As always, when doing optimization work there is no substitute for an actual performance benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

In one line: `B[np.isin(B, A[A[:, 1] <= 2][:, 0])] = 0`

Explanation:

```
c = A[:, 1] <= 2 # broadcast the original `if i[1]<=2:` check along axis=1
# i.e., mask A according to where the second values of the pairs are <= 2
d = c[:, 0] # index with the mask, and select the old `i[0]` values, here just `6`
e = np.isin(B, d) # mask B according to where the values are in the above
B[e] = 0 # and zero out those positions, i.e. where the old B value is 6
```

Comment: Compared to the comprehension approach, basically `A[A[:, 1] <= 2]` does the `if a[1] <= 2` part, and `[:, 0]` does the `a[0] for a in` part.

Comment: Yes, yes, that's the solution I was looking for. Many thanks for your help and explanation. All the best!